# How to write an sftp like password prompt?

Tags: c, posix, sftp, expect

Commands like sftp work in a way that it's not possible to pipe in user input (ex:password etc...)

Q1: How does sftp achieve this?
Q2: How do programs like expect get around this restriction?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

sftp reads input from the controlling terminal rather than just from the standard input.  Expect and similar get around it by creating a pseudo-terminal under their control and making that the controlling terminal of the process they are talking to.

Answer (score 0):

1. Requires TTY to be connected for input.
2. expect et al. allocate PTTYs to get around this.